# PowersShell UpperCase Replace

Tags: powershell, replace

Ok... after 99 different combinations...

I want to replace in thousands of files all occurences of EnumMessage.something to EnumMessage.SOMETHING so uppercase the second word. Which may be standalone or followed by a dot or followed by a (

```
$output = 'EnumMessage.test(something) and EnumMessage.Tezt andz EnumMessage.ALREAdY. ' -creplace 'EnumMessage\.(\w+)', 'EnumMessage.$1.ToUpper()'
$output
```

So the above places the function Upper there (the word) but it does not upper the second word.

Comment: I "think" what he's attempting is `$Matches[1].ToUpper()`.  However, I don't think he's got a perfect RegEx in front.

Comment: @DougMaurer nope. The `$1` isn't a variable here. [The `$` character has syntatic roles in both PowerShell and regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#regular-expressions-substitutions). In Regex substitution strings, it denotes captured groups. Be sure to either put your regular expressions between single quotation marks or insert a backtick (`) character before them.

Comment: Yes I see that now. Thanks Josef!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell 6 and later, the `-replace` operator also accepts a [script block that performs the replacement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#replacement-with-a-script-block). The script block runs once for every match.

In PowerShell 5, apply the [`Regex.Replace` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-5.0).

```
$string  = 'EnumMessage.test(something) and EnumMessage.Tezt andz EnumMessage.ALREAdY. '
$pattern = '(?<=EnumMessage\.)(\w+)'
#           (?<=EnumMessage\.)               = positive lookbehind
if ( $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge 6 ) {
    $string -replace $pattern, { $_.Value.ToUpper() }
} else {
    [regex]::Replace( $string, $pattern, { $args.Value.ToUpper() } )
}
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't realize you could reference like that.

Comment: @Steven maybe it should be  `{ $args[0].Value.ToUpper() }`, [seen here](https://powershellcookbook.com/recipe/uZgg/replace-text-in-a-string). However it works without the `[0]` index (paradoxically?).

Comment: Maybe when you've got only 1 arg it unrolls the .value property to a scalar?  Thanks for the reference I have the 1st edition cookbook on my shelf. I have a newer version in my office, but who knows when I'll be back there.

Answer (score 1):

There are definitely some challenges. I'm really not the best at RegEx. Any time I tried to leverage the $matches collection I was only able to replace the first match. There's probably something I'm forgetting about that functionality.  However, I was able to cook up the below:

```
[RegEx]::Matches($String, '(?<=EnumMessage\.)\w+') |
ForEach-Object{
    $Replace = $String.Substring($_.Index, $_.Length).ToUpper()
    $String  = $String.Remove($_.Index, $_.Length)
    $String  = $String.Insert($_.Index, $Replace)
}
$String
```

Note: I used a RegEx lookbehind, but I'm not positive that had much to do with the outcome.

The .Net `[RegEx]` class returned objects with the location of the matches in the string so I used that to strategically remove then add the ucased strings. Which should return: `EnumMessage.TEST(something) and EnumMessage.TEZT andz EnumMessage.ALREADY.`